# Indexing a document

Tags: java, html, lucene, indexing

If I'm looking to index a document (HTML) in java and the count the number of indexes, is Lucene the way to go? I have the feeling that Lucene is just a search engine.

Many thanks indeed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes! I have done this exact thing. I used [JSOUP](http://jsoup.org/) and Lucene to fetch an HTML page to index the content. `JSOUP` is a similar library to jQuery except for java. So I was able to get the `div` I wanted to index and get all the text for that. I can share examples if you want. What is your doubt and maybe I can help you with that?

**Edit**: Here is an example of a project I did a while back https://github.com/amir20/iAuthor/blob/master/wikitool/src/main/java/edu/gwu/raminfar/iauthor/wikitool/WikiTool.java#L180

It works really well if you want a true indexing service. If you want to just store the HTML in a database then Lucene might not be your choice.

Comment: Hi there. Thanks very much for the reply. I just didn't know where to start. I'm looking to take an HTML file, strip out (if needed) and index the terms in the document, minus any html markup tags. I wasn't sure if Lucene could do this. What exactly did you use JSOUP for and how did Lucene help? Thanks indeed.

Comment: cool that's exactly what i used it for. Look at my edit. I posted a link to my project. I used jsoup to get all the text for a webpage. I was actually parsing wiki pages for content and then indexing the content to search later. You can ignore the NlpService class. That was just parsing the nouns and verbs so I can have better accuracy. Does this help?

Comment: Hi, I don't need to store the HTML in a database. Just one other quick question. I just checked out JSOUP, but what exactly did you use Lucene for in this context? Thank you very much for your help. Best regards.

Comment: I pulled all the text using Jsoup and then used lucene to index the text. This allowed me to search for all documents that contained some keywords. If you don't need an indexing service then don't use lucene. You can use a regular database and you should be fine. I am still confused on what you want to do with the page. Do you need to search it later? If you don't need to store it then what are you trying to do?

Comment: Essentially, I just want to take the HTML page and index all of the content (except for the HTML markup). So the likes of content in between <p> tags, <h1> tags etc... Then I want to search each unique index in a buffer that I will write to a file at a later stage. I won't need to search it later. The indexing is only to happen once and that's it. Does that make sense? Thanks

Comment: I think so, then lucene would be right for you. You are really doing the same thing I did. Get all the HTML, parse it using jsoup, index it using lucene and store it somewhere. Then read it using lucene and search for what you want to search. You'll have to also store the url in lucene so you know later where it came from. You don't have to store the content, just set index=true and store=false.

Answer (score 1):

Well, yeah - Lucene is a search engine. (To be more precise: it's a library that allows you to build a search engine). To get a search engine, you need a text index, and Lucene provides that too. And it's a pretty powerful tool - it includes [stemmers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming) for English and a few other languages, and in my experience it runs fast even with large amounts of data.

Lucene won't parse the HTML for you, so you'll need to do that before putting the text into the index.